# don't want to give access to in app purchase for this version

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I have currently an app in Waiting for review state. I want to implement in app purchases for the next version of the app, not his one. Can I create new products and test the new version of my app with in app purchases without creating an issue for the review team?

These new products should not reflect in this version of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes of course you can.. just dont add them to the App's Metadata's In-App-Purchase section...

Comment: that will appear once u create product ids for IAP